# Run a method before a DOM is loaded in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an **img tag** whose value gets changed depending upon data. But the problem I am facing is when the value doesnt change in the DOM but I am see the value in the console using console.log. In the userImage method, I am adding an image in the image tag if the value of day shift is manager. I can see the that image tag changing to `<img class="workerid" src="/users/manager.png">` in the console but if I inspect the image tag it is just `<img class="workerid" >`. The src doesn't show up and that is the reason the image doesn't appear. Maybe I am wrong, but I think this is happening because image is loaded after DOM. Please help me solve this problem.

```
<v-form :model='management'>
  <div class="user">
   <img class="workerid" ref="workerid"/>
  </div>
</v-form>

<script>
      export default {
        data() {
          return {
            days: [
              {text: '01'},
              {text: '02'},
              {text: '03'},
              {text: '04'},
              {text: '05'},
              {text: '06'},
              {text: '07'}
            ],
            week: {
              day: '',
              daily_shift: ''
            },
            users: [
             { src: "/users/manager.png" }
            ]
        }
        created: function() {
          this.fetchWeek();
          this.userImage();
        }
        methods: {
         fetchWeek() {
          this.$axios.get('/week.json')
          .then(response => {});
         }
         userImage() {
           var user_type_image = -1;
           if (week.day_shift === "manager") {
            user_type_image = 0;
            $(this.$refs.workerid).attr("src", this.users[user_type_image].src).show();
            console.log($(this.$refs.workerid).attr("src", this.users[user_type_image].src).show());
           }
           else{
            $(this.$refs.workerid).attr("src", "").hide();
           }
         }
       }
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: You're executing `userImage` in the `created` hook but the DOM doesn't exist at that stage. Try executing it in the `mounted` hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really wouldn't recommend mixing Vue and jQuery.

Instead, you should control the image source and visibility using standard Vue controls.

For example

```html
<img class="workerid" v-show="isManager" :src="workerIdImage">
```

and in your `<script>`

```js
computed: {
  isManager () {
    return this.week.daily_shift === 'manager'
  },
  workerIdImage () {
    if (this.isManager) {
      let user_type_image = 0 // not sure if this is meant to come from elsewhere

      // you need to use 'require()' when referencing dynamic image asset paths
      return require(this.users[user_image_type].src)
    }
    return ''
  }
}
```

You can also remove the `userImage` method now.